# GA4 - filtering retail and wholesale traffic

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, google-datastream

So, I would like to filter retail and wholesale metrics on a site, but I am having issues finding the best way of doing this in GA4. I tried looking into data streams but I am not sure if that will work with my current set-up.

The way my site distinguishes retail:

1. [www.domainname.com/retail](http://www.domainname.com/retail)
2. [www.domainname.com/retail/category_example](http://www.domainname.com/retail/category_example)
3. [www.domainname.com/retail/product_example](http://www.domainname.com/retail/product_example)

And for wholesale:

1. [www.domainname.com/wholesale](http://www.domainname.com/wholesale)
2. [www.domainname.com/wholesale/category_example](http://www.domainname.com/wholesale/category_example)
3. [www.domainname.com/wholesale/product_example](http://www.domainname.com/wholesale/product_example)

So it's essentially the same domain name, (no subdomain, just a different folder).

Would I need to set-up a different property for both? Or can I just use a data stream? I have looked into content groups, but I'm unsure if that will filter everything I need like transactions, page views, purchase events, add to cart events,  etc.

I have looked through the GA4 docs but have not found a solid way of doing this - or maybe I'm just not looking in the correct place.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

GA4 does not filters like Universal Analytics.
You can add wholesale or retail as user property to you GA4 configuration tag based on page visited by user.
Then by using segmentation, you might be able to differentiate between wholesale or retail purchases

Comment: Thanks, Rushikesh, I will try using user properties and segmentation and see if I can separate both retail and wholesale.

I really don't want to set up another GA property just for that scenario, but it might be the only solution.